# Trying to add missing quarters to Name and Product in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset similar to this sample except with several thousand lines with more different Names and Products:

```
Name <- c(rep("Tom",24),
      rep("Jake",8),
      rep("Jill",5))
Product <- c(rep("Orange",12),rep("Apples",12),
         rep("Orange",8),rep("Apples",5))
Quarter <- c("2013-03-31","2013-06-30","2013-09-30","2013-12-31",
         "2014-03-31","2014-06-30","2014-09-30","2014-12-31",
         "2015-03-31","2015-06-30","2015-09-30","2015-12-31",
         "2013-03-31","2013-06-30","2013-09-30","2013-12-31",
         "2014-03-31","2014-06-30","2014-09-30","2014-12-31",
         "2015-03-31","2015-06-30","2015-09-30","2015-12-31",
         "2013-12-31","2014-03-31","2014-06-30","2014-09-30",
         "2014-12-31","2015-03-31","2015-06-30","2015-09-30",
         "2014-09-30","2014-12-31","2015-03-31","2015-06-30",
         "2015-12-31")
sample <- cbind(Name,Product,Quarter)
```

I am trying to expand the quarters to fill in the missing quarters for each Name and Product from 2013-03-31 all the way to 2015-12-31.

I have tried using the expand.grid function to add the missing quarters, however, it just creates all combinations using the factors. For example using

```
expanded <- expand.grid(Name = unique(sample$Name),
                    Product = unique(sample$Product),
                    Quarter = unique(sample$Quarter))
```

Forces Jake to have products Apple when he should have only oranges and Jill to include Oranges when she should only have apples.

Preferably I would want the data set to looks like this:

```
Name <- c(rep("Tom",24),
      rep("Jake",12),
      rep("Jill",12))
Product <- c(rep("Orange",12),rep("Apples",12),
         rep("Orange",12),rep("Apples",12))
Quarter <- c(rep(c("2013-03-31","2013-06-30","2013-09-30","2013-12-31",
         "2014-03-31","2014-06-30","2014-09-30","2014-12-31",
         "2015-03-31","2015-06-30","2015-09-30","2015-12-31"),4))
preferred <- cbind(Name,Product,Quarter)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we convert `sample` to a `data.frame`

```
df <- data.frame(sample)
```

Then we use `expand()` from the `tidyr` package:

```
tidyr::expand(df, nesting(Name, Product), Quarter)
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [48 x 3]
#
#     Name Product    Quarter
#   (fctr)  (fctr)     (fctr)
#1    Jake  Orange 2013-03-31
#2    Jake  Orange 2013-06-30
#3    Jake  Orange 2013-09-30
#4    Jake  Orange 2013-12-31
#5    Jake  Orange 2014-03-31
#6    Jake  Orange 2014-06-30
#7    Jake  Orange 2014-09-30
#8    Jake  Orange 2014-12-31
#9    Jake  Orange 2015-03-31
#10   Jake  Orange 2015-06-30
#..    ...     ...        ...
```